# Mysql query to Model, Resource Model, Collection - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, model, resource-model

I can easily get or set value using ORM. I felt difficult to convert mysql query logic to Model, Resource Model, Collection(ORM).

for example I am getting last one hour data using the below query

```
select * from chennai_cancel_order where cancel_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

but I don't have idea about how to apply above logic to ORM.

Similarly more way of query is possible like **order by, descending, limit**..... etc.

please give some clarity about how to handle Mysql query in ORM.

Comment: have u create model/resource model?

Comment: yes I have created, I can able to get and set value. While getting I don't know how to apply condition like mysql query for fetching particular data

Comment: Why do yon not calculate DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) at client side (in php)?

Comment: do you mean using object manager use the query directly in php?

Comment: i mean that  you can write code like $chennaiCancelOrderCollection->addFilter('cancel_date', ['gt' => new DataTime()->modify('-1 hour')->format(DateTime::ISO8601)])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento 2 still can work with `Zend_Db_Expr` for arbitrary SQL expressions in filters. Given a collection, use `addFilter` for the where condition:

```
$chennaiCancelOrderCollection->addFilter(
    'cancel_date',
    ['gt' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)']);
```